# Removing <p> tag throws Handler execution resulted in exception: null

Tags: java, spring, ckeditor

I am working on Spring MVC project and in this project I am trying to remove first and last 'p' tag from the input. The problem is, when i am trying to remove the p tag with following code

```
detail.setHindiParagraph(detail.getHindiParagraph().replaceFirst("<p>", "").replaceAll("</p>$", ""));
```

it throws following exception

```
 2017-06-03 17:38:09 DEBUG QuestionServiceImpl:62 - Question HindiParagraph--Question Para is <img src="data:image/png;base64,.... />
 2017-06-03 17:38:09 DEBUG QuestionServiceImpl:66 - Question QuestionType---Single Choice
 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: null
```

but when i debug the removing process

```
 logger.debug("Question HindiParagraph--"+detail.getHindiParagraph().replaceFirst("<p>", "").replaceAll("</p>$", ""));
```

it's working fine for me and produces expected result without p tag as printed in stacktrace(line 1- stacktrace), and one more thing when i am trying to save input value without removing the p tag it's working fine, so as i think it's not wiring conf issue.

I have no clue why it's happening, Can any one help me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? How do you know the exception about is related to your code? Looks to me like a wiring conf issue.

Comment: @MinhKieu no this is not wiring issue, once i remove detail.setHindiParagraph(detail.getHindiParagraph().replaceFirst("<p>", "").replaceAll("</p>$", "")); code, it's all working fine for me.

Comment: please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @MinhKieu stacktrace edited, and i have nothing more than it.

Comment: its a warning! If you google "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: null" you will see its related wiring up Spring MVC.

Comment: @MinhKieu you are right but in my case i am configured "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" for "uncaughtException" exception either for "org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException.DataAccessException" and org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException and many more.. and if you saying that it is related to mapping then why it's working when i am saving without removing p tag.

Comment: Perhaps that line throw an exception which gets pickup by SimpleMappingExcept‌​ionResolver? One thing to try is to break that statement into multiple lines and bug by printing out the result line-by-line.